# A system of four equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, 3d

> Given the system of equations
> $$\begin{cases}
> x-2y-z=1 \\\\x+z=-1 \\\\ -x-y+z=-1 \\\\ x-y-3z=k
> \end{cases} $$
> where $k\in \mathbb{R}$ it is known that for $k=9$ the four planes given by the four equations above bound a tetrahedron. What is the volume of the tetrahedron?

It is not difficult to find the volume of the tetrahedron. Just use $V=\frac{1}{6}\det[\textbf{a b  c}]$ where **a,b,c** are the vectors spanning the tetrahedron.

I am confused by one thing in this question. And that is that, equation $2$ is not a plane, it is a line so I can't see how three planes and one line will ever bound a tetrahedron. Furthermore, when I plot the equations I don't get a tetrahedron at all, I get this: -

[image]

Is there a mistake in the problem description, or am I not understanding something correctly here?

Comment: I assume you mean volume not area? By the way, all four equations are definitely planes in 3D, not lines

Comment: @DavidQuinn Yes, I meant volume sorry. But I thought a plane was spanned by two vectors, and that requires two free parameters in the equation, which there is not. How is equation 2 describing a plane?

Comment: planes in Cartesian form are equations of the form $ax+by+cz=d$ for various $a,b,c,d$

Comment: @DavidQuinn Oh I see, so I can just vary $y$ as much as I want, but it won't have any effect on the equation of the plane. But when plotting I still don't see how they bound a tetrahedron.

Comment: It looks like you're going to have to find the four vertices of this tetrahedron. So, for example, solving planes 1,2 and 3 gives$(x,y,z)=(0,0,-1)$. Solving planes 1,2 and 4 gives $(x,y,z)=(6,6,-7)$ and so on...

Comment: Thank you @DavidQuinn